# correct query for join two querys

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this query for select a list

```
$sql="select *  from buy_log where (client_id  not in 
                (select selected_client_id from action_log where media_id=buy_log.media_id and client_id=$client_id ) 
                    and totalVisit>0 and coin_id=3 or coin_id=4 or coin_id=5)";
```

and this is my second select

```
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $media_id = $row['media_id'];
            $sql2 = "select * from comment_media,comment_list where comment_list.id=comment_media.id and media_id='$media_id' order by rand() limit 2";
            }
```

i try to use join for one query and this is my try :

```
SELECT S.*,WW.Comments,WW.Comments_id
FROM buy_log S

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT M.media_id,GROUP_CONCAT(W.Comment SEPARATOR '!###!') as Comments,GROUP_CONCAT(W.id SEPARATOR ',') as Comments_id
    FROM comment_list W,comment_media as M
    Where W.id=M.id and M.media_id='$media_id' and W.used = 0

) WW
        ON S.media_id = WW.media_id
            where (client_id  not in 
                (select selected_client_id from action_log where media_id=S.media_id and client_id='1234' ) 
                    and totalVisit>0 and coin_id=3 or coin_id=4 or coin_id=5)
```

but here is my problem

```
Where W.id=M.id and M.media_id='$media_id' and W.used = 0
```

I don't know how can i set `$media_id`

any solution ?

**UPDATE**
Tables Info :
[Tables Info : Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NNSg.png)

Comment: Is media_id available in buy_log?  You might be able to just reference it as S.Media_id

Comment: Yes,media_id available in buy_log. But we can't do this `Unknown column 'S.media_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

You're extracting media id from that original query, looping through results and using the media id to assign the value $media_id in the php loop, where you perform another query.

The join seems syntactically right just need to reference the buy_log table inside the subquery.

```
SELECT S.*,WW.Comments,WW.Comments_id
FROM buy_log S

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT M.media_id,GROUP_CONCAT(W.Comment SEPARATOR '!###!') as Comments,GROUP_CONCAT(W.id SEPARATOR ',') as Comments_id
    FROM comment_list W,comment_media as M
    Where W.id=M.id and M.media_id= S.media_id and W.used = 0

) WW
        ON S.media_id = WW.media_id
            where (client_id  not in 
                (select selected_client_id from action_log where media_id=S.media_id and client_id='1234' ) 
                    and totalVisit>0 and coin_id=3 or coin_id=4 or coin_id=5)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, however i was try that code but that is not correct `Unknown column 'S.media_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Can you provide your table schema?

Comment: please check pic link in question

Answer (score 0):

I guess that first query can be rewritten as follows... does it help?

```
SELECT b.media_id  
  FROM buy_log b
  LEFT 
  JOIN action_log a
    ON a.selected_client_id = b.client_id
   AND a.media_id = b.media_id 
   AND a.client_id = $client_id 
 WHERE b.totalVisit > 0 
   AND b.coin_id IN(3,4,5)
   AND a.selected_client_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: please check pic link in question, thanks for code and answer but i can't get correct result again :(

Comment: I don't do pictures- see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query